# Should one retake the tetanus vaccination?

Tags: tetanus-shot

I have heard from a doctor that one should take vaccination for tetanus every 10 years. On the other hand, I have also heard from a medical researcher that there are no known cases where one has got a tetanus after he or she has got a tetanus vaccination. Which one is correct?